# Pygame Mixer not playing audio

Tags: python, pygame, mp3

I've been working on this for a while but everything I find seems to be a dead end so I could use some help troubleshooting.

```
import pygame

file = open("C:\\Users\\MyName\\Music\\oggTest.ogg")

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

This code is supposed to grab an audio file and play it using the mixer from pygame. Very simple, and I've seen other questions here asking about how to do it but mine's still not working for some reason. Right now, I have no errors when I'm running the code. The only problem is that nothing happens. No audio gets played. I have a hunch that it has something to do with my IDE (pycharm), but I don't know for sure if that's the case. Also, the filepath part is a bit confusing to me. I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work but perhaps I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance for helping out.

As per the advice of a YT video, I converted the mp3 file I originally had to an ogg file. Not sure if that was necessary, and honestly I'd prefer not to have to do it in the future.

Comment: This works for me, but only in python2.  It will work in python3 if the string filename-path is passed to `...music.load()` instead of an open file handle.

Comment: Okay, I tried doing that but nothing seems to change. I'm using Python 3.7 because it's compatible with pygame but not sure if I have to go back further? And I don't think I'm doing anything stupid. I have my volume up, no headphones in, nothing.

Comment: You tried running it outside of PyCharm right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer after a bit more research. Taking out the pygame.init() worked. I guess it didn't like doing both pygame.init() and pygame.mixer.init() for some reason.